# ORACLE Extract last data with different keys within the table

Tags: sql, oracle

DATA

```
A1 - B1 - DATA1
A1 - B1 - DATA2
A1 - B1 - DATA3
A1 - B2 - DATA1
A1 - B2 - DATA2
A1 - B3 - DATA1
A1 - B3 - DATA2
A1 - B3 - DATA3
```

Desired results

```
A1 - B1 - DATA3
A1 - B2 - DATA2
A1 - B3 - DATA3
```

Extract only the last data from each second column
The third column [DATA] does not need to be sorted.

Comment: What have you tried yet ? Please post your current attempt.

Comment: How do you recognize what data is the last one? Do you have a column that holds input date or is it obvious from string in your `DATA` column? Answer that no-named-horse gave you is correct for data as you showed it to us, when it truly is 'DATA3' > 'DATA2' (by string value, because 'DATA' == 'DATA' and 3 > 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your sample data, it seems that you want a simple group by:

```
select column_1, column_2, max(column_3)
from the_table
group by column_1, column_2
order by column_1, column_2;
```